# delete the original item from the DOM after drop using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Hi I am using jquery sortable and drag to remove item. The item can be drag but it didn't stay on the dropping position. Would you tell me how to do it.

There is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      if (!ui.item.data('tag') && !ui.item.data('handle')) {
        ui.item.data('tag', true);
        ui.item.fadeTo(400, 0.1);
        ui.item.remove();
      }
    }
  });

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
    ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table style="border:5px solid red; width: 50%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:5px solid black">
      <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">One</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Two</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to stay if you remove it from the DOM?

Comment: Do you think that dragging makes a copy, so you need to remove the original? That's not how it works. It just relocates the element in the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar with `helper:"clone"` it does make a copy.  It's unclear why OP attempted to remove the original within the sort instead of a drop event - but not needed either way if they use the default "move" option for draggable.

Answer (score 0):

To *copy* an item from the left list to the right list, you use

```
helper:"clone"
```

if you don't want to *copy* but instead *move* then don't specify a helper or specify the default:

```
helper:"original"
```

The reason the item is disappearing once dropped is that you are changing the "dropped" item in `sortable` - this is the wrong place to do this. In `sortable`, `ui.item` is the item being *sorted* (not being dropped - that operation has already completed).

You can confirm this by moving "Item 2" (eg) on the right panel to a different position in your original code; it will be removed.

So the simple solution is to remove the ui.item.fade and ui.item.remove within sortable.

Combined with not creating a clone, should give you the results you are after.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      if (!ui.item.data('tag') && !ui.item.data('handle')) {
        ui.item.data('tag', true);
        //ui.item.fadeTo(400, 0.1);
        //ui.item.remove();
      }
    }
  });

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    //helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("ul, li").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
    li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table style="border:5px solid red; width: 50%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border:5px solid black">
      <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">One</li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Two</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```